# Variable is not being recognized outside function even after making it global JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can't get my head around why this is not working I have also tried window.variable and that doesn't work from my understanding anything without the var keyword is at global level.

I would expect the window.alert to work but it is saying it is undefined I also thought it was perhaps because i was using the this keyword so I tried making another variable it did the same thing and before you ask I am pressing a key and still undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  flag = false;

  var x = $('.inpbox');
  x.keyup(function() {
    logVal = this.value + 'helloooo';
    console.log(logVal);
  });
  window.alert(logVal);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'searchbar.php',
    data: {
      val: 'logVal'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
  });


  $('#abcd').click(function() {

    setInterval(function() {
      via_ajax();
    }, 1000);

    function via_ajax() {
      flag = true;
      if (flag == true) {};
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'searchbar.php',
        data: {
          val: 'logVal'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
      });
    };
  });

});
```

Comment: Well, when `alert`is executed `window.logVal` is really `undefined`. What is expected?

Comment: use $(x).keyup instead of x.keyup

Comment: whenever i type it logs everything so im expecting it to output that it logs everything inside the function but not out.

Comment: You clearly have a **timing** problem. *When* does `alert` occur? *When* does the `keyup` callback occur?

Comment: off topic: `flag = true; if(flag == true) {};` is probably one of my all time favorite code snippets.

Comment: isn't your `data` object in your ajax call a literal instead of the variable itself?

Comment: hmm ye but i want it to be the variable thats why i added that hellooo string part on the end to see when i posted it.

Comment: I just pasted that one piece of code (the `keyup` part) in JSFiddle and the first error I encounter is that the variable `logVal` is not defined. So try putting `var logVal;` above `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: make your via_ajax()  as a callback method for the keyup event function. So the ajax call will happen only when the key up even is fired.

Comment: i'll give it a go

Comment: @LuudJacobs - it COULD be "flag = <?=somevar ?>" and {to be filled in later or deleted when asking question}

Answer (score 0):

You change it to something like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").keyup(function(){
       logVal = this.value + 'helloooo';
      ajax_Val();
  });


});

function ajax_Val()
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'searchbar.php',
    data: {
      val: logVal
    },
    dataType: 'json',
  });
}

</script>
```